# Chain 2 queries in RTK Query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query

What is the proper way to chain queries if the 2nd query requires a parameter that is returned by the 1st?

```
const { data: user } = useGetUserQuery();
```

The user object contains an ID that is used to run

```
const { data: userBio} = useGetUserBioQuery(user.id);
```

How do I make sure the 2nd one runs only after the 1st one is fulfilled?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `skip` option:

```js
const { data: user, isFulfilled: userFulfilled } = useGetUserQuery();
const { data: userBio} = useGetUserBioQuery(user.id, { skip: !userFulfilled });
```

Or a `skipToken`:

```js
import { skipToken } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'

const { data: user, isFulfilled: userFulfilled } = useGetUserQuery();
const { data: userBio} = useGetUserBioQuery(userFulfilled ? user.id : skipToken);
```

Comment: I tried it but Typescript doesn't seem to be happy with it. Is there a better way than just shut it down with the non-null assertion operator?

Comment: the skipToken approach, but no destructuring of your result variable. that will keep the correlation isFulfilled => data is not undefined

Answer (score 6):

The usage section of the RTK Query docs also provides another example on how to combine multiple requests with one single query that I found very usefull for that use case:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#performing-multiple-requests-with-a-single-query

Answer (score 4):

we can use `skip` flag to make sure if there is user id

```
const { data: user } = useGetUserQuery();
const { data: userBio} = useGetUserBioQuery(user.id, { skip: !user.id });
```