# Why is my RTK Query "skip" parameter not working?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux, rtk-query

What I'm trying to do is fetch an array of objects, then fetch data related to the first object in the array.

```
const progress = useSelector(state => state.progress);
const appInfo = useSelector(state => state.appInfo);

const {
    data: steps,
    isLoading: isStepsLoading,
    isSuccess: isStepsSuccess
} = useGetAllStepsQuery()

const {
  data: questions
} = useGetQuestionsQuery({app_id: appInfo.id, step_parameter: steps[progress.currentStepIndex].step_parameter}, {skip: isStepsLoading})
```

The problem I'm having is that attempting to extract the `step_parameter` from the `steps` array is throwing a `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')` error: in other words, it's as if the `useGetQuestionsQuery` is being called before the  `useGetAllStepsQuery` is finished. I've added a `skip` parameter to the request, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505094/chain-2-queries-in-rtk-query), and tried various values with it (e.g. `!isStepsSuccess`), none of them resolve this problem. I've also tried assigning the `step_parameter` conditionally, like this:

```
step_parameter: isStepsSuccess ? steps[progress.currentStepIndex].step_parameter : ''
```

Which does prevent the error, but it also appears to prevent the questions call from ever being made. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hmm. I would expect that the `skip` approach would work here. Can you put together a CodeSandbox that shows what you're doing there?