# using 2 interdependent hooks

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I need to use 2 hooks that depend on each other: useHook1() returns a list of ids and useHook2(id) is called on each of the ids and returns a name.

Basically what I want to do is:

```js
const [allData, setData] = useState<Playerdata[]>([]);

const { data, isFetching, isError } = useHook1();

useEffect(() => {
  if (data) {
    setData(data)
  }
})

// THIS PART ***
let tempData = []
data.forEach((id) => {
  const { data: idData, isFetching, isError } = useHook2(id)
  tempData.push(idData)
})
setData(tempData)
// ***
```

But the *** part above gives error "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render." because I'm calling the second hook in a loop. The hooks are RTK queries: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chain 2 queries in RTK Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69505094/chain-2-queries-in-rtk-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code breaks the [Rules of Hooks](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html), hooks cannot be called in loops. You may need to use the [lazy query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery) version of hook #2 so you can call the trigger function within a loop and wait for its result.

An example implementation could look similar to the following:

```js
const [allData, setData] = useState<Playerdata[]>([]);

const { data, isFetching, isError } = useHook1Query();
const [query2Trigger] = useHook2LazyQuery();

useEffect(() => {
  const getAllData = async (data) => {
    const allData = await Promise.all(data.map(async id => {
      const { data } = await query2Trigger(id);
      return data;
    }));
    setData(allData);
  };

  if (data) {
    getAllData(data);
  }
}, [data, query2Trigger]);
```